# How to assign a collection or document to a specific user in firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm learning how to use firebase and now I'm trying to make something like a school managment system using html, css, javascript and firebase.

This is how I add homeworks

```
const formHomework = document.querySelector('#formHW');

formHomework.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection('university').doc('offers').collection('list').add({

        nameHW:  formHW['nameHW'].value,
        nameOffer: formHW ['nameOffer'].value,
        nameTopic: formHW['nameTopic'].value,
        purpHW: formHW['purpHW'].value,
        descriptionHW: formHW['descriptionHW'].value,
        knowField: formHW['knowField'].value,
        date: formHW['date'].value


    }).then(()=>{
        formHW.reset();
        window.alert("Homework added");
    })

})
```

I already know how to create documents and collections by submitting a form

What I want to do now is:

for the **teachers** to create content and homeworks for their own classes only

I'm clueless as to how achieve this, any help is gladly appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done with a collection for all users that hold documents for each user named by their auth UID. this typically contains their respective sub-collections and any meta properties you want to associate with that user such as roles, permissions, tags, etc.

You can also extend this to also associate the homework with a class ID, so all users are able to query for any homework that contains a property `classID` with the ID and sort by date. This does mean each user will need a list of classes they are in and the respective class ID's

Comment: I get what you're trying to say but I have some problems trying to apply your solution in the project if you can provide me with an example I'd really apreciate it